# Parsing comma separated list from HTML response in Go

Tags: html, list, parsing, go, slice

I am receiving an HTML response in format

[["var1", "var2", "var3"], ["foo", "doo", "goo"], ["moo", "loo", "roo"]]

Is the only way to parse this by using regex on brackets and then looping and slicing each slice again by comma or is there some more efficient way to get the lists into slices? There are tens of thousands of "rows" so performance could be of some significance.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: _"Is the only way to parse this by using regex?"_ No, of course not. Parsing this with regexp would be the last to come to my mind. This looks like a JSON array of arrays, you  could try to parse it with `encoding/json`. It also supports decoding it as it's streaming in...

Comment: @icza It was the last to come to my mind as well, so we have something in common. This is the exact reason I posted the question.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is using `encoding/json` as @icza suggested

```
v := `[["var1", "var2", "var3"], ["foo", "doo", "goo"], ["moo", "loo", "roo"]]`
var s [][]string
json.Unmarshal([]byte(v), &s)
fmt.Print(s)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Did not conceive of that structure as JSON. Live and learn.